# Change names of x-axis in plot

Tags: r, graph, diagram

I want to create a line diagram based on the following data:

```
Block <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
Breaks <- c("1 Mio. - 2 Mio.", "2 Mio. - 3 Mio.", "3 Mio. - 4 Mio.", "4 Mio. - 5 Mio.", "5 Mio. - 6 Mio.") 
Minimum <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
MEAN <- c(4,5,4,6,7)
```

Now, I want to plot the data, showing the Breaks on the x-axis and the MEAN on the y-Axis. However, I run into an error in doing so "Error in plot.window(...): "xlim" necessary".

I then changed the code that I use the minimum values on the x-axis and I get my line diagramm. However, now the x-axis shows the values of the minimum, but I want the names of the breaks.

My current code is:

```
plot(data$Minimium, data$MEAN, type = "b",
     xlab = "Size", ylab = "Mean Value",
     main = "Mean Value per Size")
```

How can I change the description of the x-axis for that I see the breaks ("1 Mio. - 2 Mio.", "2 Mio. - 3 Mio.", "3 Mio. - 4 Mio.", "4 Mio. - 5 Mio.", "5 Mio. - 6 Mio.") instead of the minimum values?

To clarify: I want to change the highlightend line:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `xaxt = 'n'` to prevent an x axis from being drawn, then specify a new x axis with specific labels:

```r
plot(data$Minimum, data$MEAN, type = "b",
     xlab = "Size", ylab = "Mean Value",
     main = "Mean Value per Size", xaxt = 'n')
axis(1, at = data$Minimum, labels = data$Breaks)
```

[image]

Or do it in ggplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(Breaks, MEAN, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = 'white', size = 4) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Allan! I tried your first options. Unfortunately, for there are two lines of descriptions now. This results in the fact that you cant really see the names anymore. Do you have a trick for that it only shows one line of axis description? Or a way to delete the initial description?

Comment: @Li4991 You can see from my example that there aren't two lines. Have you copy-pasted the code exactly?

Comment: Found the mistake! Now, everything works. Thanks!!